# How to change variable of integral back to x?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

So I was working on the integral of $\dfrac{\cos(x)}{1 + \sin(x)}$ and got it down to $\dfrac{1}{1 + u^2}$ using a substitution. I don't think my professor will allow a direct result to $\arctan(x)$, so I tried doing another substitution, but I can't logically get the result's variable back to $x$. Where did I make an error?

Comment: At the beginning, you have $u = \sin x$. But a couple of lines later, you have $u = \tan x$. That's confusing. Instead, how about $u = \tan v$? At the end, you'll get $v + C$, and then you unravel the variables: $v + C = \arctan u + C = \arctan(\sin x) + C$.

Comment: That is a horribly confusing write up! Do what @Théophile suggests - pick a third variable for the second substitution.

Comment: $\arctan(u)+C=\arctan(\sin(x))+C$